# upload image from image URL using retrofit in Android?

Tags: android, retrofit2

I have little bit different kind of problem related to upload image using retrofit. I am getting image from server with correct image path....Now I want to upload same image on server to different table....Problem I'm facing that I have Image URL which getting from server not file path???Any Idea

When I'm passing image URL to MultipartBody It giving me problem NO file or dir found

Comment: download it into internal storage -> get the path -> reupload it

Comment: `Now I want to upload same image on server to different table....Problem I'm facing that I have Image URL` That is irrelevant. And not a problem. You have used that url to download it. So now you have an image. You are going to upload that image to a different url. You do not need a file path if you have that image in memory.

Comment: That is problem buddy don't have image in memory just image URL which getting from server